# MySQL Query Simplification (Help Pls)

Tags: mysql

I transferred a CSV file to MySQL containing data on various movies and am practicing writing queries to answer various questions I come up with. I was trying to write a query that would show every person who appeared in the list as both a director and an actor. Below is the DDL for the table and the query I came up with.

```
-- DDL for table creation
CREATE TABLE `moviedata` (
  `movietitle` varchar(50),
  `releasedate` date,
  `wikipediaurl` varchar(128),
  `genre` varchar(50),
  `director_one` varchar(50),
  `director_two` varchar(50),
  `cast_one` varchar(50),
  `cast_two` varchar(50),
  `cast_three` varchar(50),
  `cast_four` varchar(50),
  `cast_five` varchar(50),
  `budget` int,
  `revenue` int;
)
```

```
-- List of people who appear in table as both a cast member and director
WITH 
    director_list_cte AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT(directorname)
        FROM (
            SELECT director_one AS directorname
            FROM moviedata
            WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(director_one) > 1
            UNION
            SELECT director_two AS directorname
            FROM moviedata
            WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(director_two) > 1 
            ) director_subq
    ),
    cast_list_cte AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT(castname)
        FROM (
            SELECT cast_one AS castname
            FROM moviedata
            WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(cast_one) > 1
            UNION
            SELECT cast_two AS castname
            FROM moviedata
            WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(cast_two) > 1
            UNION
            SELECT cast_three AS castname
            FROM moviedata
            WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(cast_three) > 1
            UNION
            SELECT cast_four AS castname
            FROM moviedata
            WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(cast_four) > 1
            UNION
            SELECT cast_five AS castname
            FROM moviedata
            WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(cast_five) > 1    
            ) cast_subq
        )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT directorname AS person_name
    FROM director_list_cte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT castname AS person_name
    FROM cast_list_cte
) all_subq
GROUP BY all_subq.person_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

While this does work I have to imagine there is a somewhat simpler way to accomplish this. I originally tried to INNER JOIN the two cte's to check for similarities however there is not really anything to join them on. I also do not know how to equate blank cells in a CSV file to NULL values in a DBMS, hence the CHAR_LENGTH shortcut to filter out the blank cells. Let me know what ideas y'all have.

Comment: It would be much simpler if you provided us with the format of your `moviedata` table.

Comment: @AndyPreston added DDL for table creation to post

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of the query is caused by your table design.

Separate the directors and the cast and the genre from the movie table into separate table(s) and have a new tables that connects the movies to the director/cast/genres.

If you are fixed with the table design, create similar views on the current table.

You can take a look at MySQL sample database [Sakila](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) which contains similar movie data.

Comment: I 100% agree, this was just a random table I found online and just wanted to test myself. I am already familiar with the Sakila database and have messed around with that a little bit, just wanted to see what it was like working with a database that didn't have any keys and was just a simple spreadsheet.